# How do I delay/schedule sending a message in alpine (/realpine/pine)?

Tags: email, alpine-mail

I want to send out my email(s) on Monday morning, not now. Is there a plugin / modification (or feature) for alpine to let me schedule when a message gets sent?

I use an smtp service on my campus. If (re)(al)pine can't do what I want, would there be a way to set something up on my own machine (Ubuntu) that keeps ALL messages until Monday morning? e.g. though it wouldn't be ideal,  I could do something to switch my SMTP server in pine to something local that actually delayed contacting the SMTP server?

Comment: You may have graduated by now (unless you're faculty), but something that you *can* do is postpone the message. Of course then you manually have to do all the sending when you get to campus.

Answer (score 2):

What about saving it to a file and schedule an `at` job to send it at your chosen time with `sendmail`?

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a way to do this in mind? From alpine, when editing a draft, there is no option to save to disk. Is alpine scriptable somehow, letting me add an option? And would sendmail read the headers for me or would the draft need to be processed somehow to send it to the right places?

Answer (score 1):

Install a local [MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent) (i.e. an SMTP server). Ubuntu favors [Postfix](http://packages.ubuntu.com/postfix). Queuing posts until they can be sent is the job of an MTA. You'll need to configure your MTA with the address of your campus's SMTP server as an outgoing relay.

Ubuntu's Postfix package comes configured to flush the mail queue when the Internet connection comes up, so if that's what you want to do, you won't have to configure anything else.

If you want to delay the sending of a specific email even though it could be sent now, [use `at`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48942).